# Geeeting particular value from json and store in one variable

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I need to get a particular value from the JSON and store it in the variable in LWC is there any way I can do it:

```
asd==[
   {
      "ABC":"ytyffy98948",
      "custui":"009686758jbnvnvm",
      "CAR__c":"YUI",
      "RAF__C":f,
      "FAN__C":"78tu8u"
      
      
   }
]
const sdfr== asd.FAN__C;
```

I am getting the value in `sdfr` as undefined. the actual value in JSON is 78tu8u

kindly help me out for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a syntax error in it. You need to use a single `=` sign for the assignment.

```
asd=[
   {
      "ABC":"ytyffy98948",
      "custui":"009686758jbnvnvm",
      "CAR__c":"YUI",
      "RAF__C":"f",
      "FAN__C":"78tu8u"  
   }
]
```

Also `asd` is an array, not an object.
So you need to access it like below.

```
const sdfr = asd[0].FAN__C;
```